# Proving that two subspace are orthogonal by the fact that the projection transformation satisfies: $P = P*$

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

Let $V$ be a unitary space with finite dimentions.

Let $L_1, L_2$ be subspaces of $V$ such that $V = L_1 \oplus L_2$.

Let $P$ be the projection transformation on $L_1$ parallel to $L_2$.

Prove that if $P* = P$ so $L_1 = L_2^{\perp}$

### I tried:

Now define 2 general vectors: 
$$
v,v' \in V
$$

They can be represented as:

$$
v = l_1 + l_2
$$
$$
v' = l'_1 + l'_2
$$

For some:

$$
l_1,l'_1 \in L_1
$$

$$
l_2,l'_2 \in L2
$$

Now if $P*=P$ it holds that:

$$
<Pv,v'> = <v,Pv'> = <l_1, l'_1+l'_2> = <l_1+l_2, l'_1>
$$

Opening both sides:

$$
<l_1,l'_1> + <l_1,l'_2> = <l_1,l'_1> + <l_2,l'_1>
$$

Therefore we got:

$$
<l_1,l'_2> = <l_2,l'_1>
$$

From that, i want somehow to conclude that both sides equal to zero, therefore $L_1 = L_2^{\perp}$

Not sure how to continue

I would like a hint - those are homework.

Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so the answer is just by taking:

$$
l_1 \in L_1, l_2 \in L_2
$$

And then do:

$$
<Pl_1,l_2> = <l_1,Pl_2>
$$

Remembering:

$$
Pl_1 = l_1, Pl_2 = 0.
$$